# Self certificate in local network on IIS project ASP.NET Core - Not secure (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, iis, ssl-certificate, self-signed

im tryng to make the https in my project in asp.net core (only in local network).

On cmd i have create a self certificate with this command line:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=192.168.1.208" -FriendlyName "192.168.1.208" -DnsName "192.168.1.208" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(36) -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

On IIS i bind the port and the certificate like this:

[image]

Now if i go on chrome and i search https://192.168.1.208:7001 i have this:
[image]

I tried so many attempts, and now i dont know how to resolve this, can someone help me?

Comment: IP addresses cannot be used in such cases. Fake a domain name if you have to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now i have create a domain and its works, you saved me